# How do I perform a VLOOKUP to the left without explicitly naming the left column range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, microsoft-excel

I have an array of data that I want to look up a specific phrase from. Once the phrase is found I would like to output the value or phrase of the cell to the direct left of the cell that’s found. I would like to be able to use this formula without explicitly naming the columns because there is not a specific column with all of the data that I need.Please let me know if I need to explain further. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. You need to supply more information, including, I suggest, some sample data for an example of the scenario that you are anticipating. If you don't want to "name the column" to be returned, then you need to explain how you propose to identify the column that you want to return.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is days old now, and there has been no response to community contributor "Tedinoz." But I agree that we'd need a link to a spreadsheet with realistic data and hand-entered "desired results" as a starting point.